# iPhone: UIImage obtained after rendering a view is solid black

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm using this method to render a `UIView` into a `UIImage`:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

The resulting image is of the right size (as shown by the UIImage's `size` property), but its contents is solid black colour. The view passed there definitely contains some graphics, but it's not rendered. Any idea why?

Comment: Is the view hidden? I'm not sure, but it might not work for hidden views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I use to capture images of a UIView:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[view.layer renderInContext:context];

UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;
```

Your code looks fine to me. You can try swapping mine out to see if it helps, but I'd cite it to be a separate issue from the code you posted.

Comment: Woohoo, your code solved that for me. Reason? You hardcode opaque to NO, and in my view it was set to YES incorrectly. Thank you for this paste.

Comment: The underlying problem is that (AIUI) the "opaque" maps to CALayer.opaque, which "only affects ... whether the generated bitmap has an alpha channel" when your view implements -drawRect: (or the equivalent CoreAnimation methods).